# Add a cell to the bottom of UITableView that only appears when there is no more content

Tags: ios, uitableview, parse-platform

So I want to add a cell to the bottom of a UITableView that only appears when there is no more content.

The goal is that when there is no more users in the list I want to have a cell that shows up with Twitter, Facebook etc buttons so the user can invite more users. Any hints?

All the best

Comment: Do you mean a UITableView?

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek -  Subclassing the cell in different ways. But no luck

Comment: What do you mean when there is no more content? You just want a cell at the bottom of the table every time the user scrolls to the bottom?

Comment: Yes. But only when there is no no more information in the row list.

Answer (score 0):

Start off by creating different `NSTableViewCell`'s - one for your regular data and one for your "Social Media" cell at the end.

In the `UITableViewDataSource` you can report the number of rows as being one greater than the total number of rows for your data

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [mDataSource count] + 1;
}
```

Then, in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, check if it's the last row, and return your "social media" cell.

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    if (indexPath.row == [mDataSource count] + 1) {
        cellIdentifier = @"SocialCell";
    }

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    ...
```

}